# Allowing any generic type in method parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to make a method that will take in any generic as a parameter, for example, I have the following method that will take a MyGenericClass<string> but I'd like to make it so I could also pass it a MyGenericClass<int> or MyGenericClass<anything else>. How do I go about doing that?

```
        private void foo(MyGenericClass<string> tag)
        {
               
           
        }
```

Comment: make it generic as well `private void foo<T>(MyGenericClass<T> tag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 private void foo<T>(MyGenericClass<T> tag)
 {

 }
```

If your generic class work with specific type you should modify method as well:

```
 class MyGenericClass<T> where T : struct
 {

 }
```

Method:

```
 private static void foo<T>(MyGenericClass<T> tag) where T : struct
 {

 }
```

For more details you can read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So if I understand right, even if I'm not doing nothing specific to generics at all in the method, if I'm going to be receiving a generic as a parameter the method must be generic?

Comment: What does "doing nothing specific to generics at all in the method" mean to you?

Comment: "if I'm going to be receiving a generic as a parameter the method must be generic" - that's a bit weirdly worded. If a parameter to a method contains a generic type then either the method or the class (or a class that encloses the current class) must define the generic parameter.

Comment: Sorry for not wording it well, still learning, what I mean is I don't actually care what <T> is, and it's never actually used in the method. Everything done in the method works regardless of what type the generic is, as that part of the object is never actually touched. 

You guessed correctly at what I was trying to ask though, since your second comment answers it perfectly.